# Android webview scaling issue

Tags: android, android-webview, viewport, autoscaling

I have a `Grid View` in `WebView`(Android) and need to determine number of items that can be fit on the screen. I need this number to be sent to server to retrieve those many items from server. When I query the screen size in my Activity, it returns **width : 800** and and **height: 522**(in landscape). But when the width is queried from javascript, the width returned is 1063. I have done appropriate settings for `Viewport`.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

As both the values are different, it messes my calculations. The `WebView` display more items than my calculations per items.

Can someone please point out what am I messing up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to map the webview with the screen layout by using setInitialScale over the webview.

Initial scale is defined in % so you need to specify something like below

```
int scalingFactor = ((float)800/(float)1063)*100

mPageWeb.setInitialScale(scalingFactor);
```

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: I had already set Webview.setInitialScale(100); I need to know why I get 1063. This value is returned for a particular device. I am sure other devices might return other values. Hence I cannot use the solution you have mentioned. I need to know the reason why I receive that value, so that I can formulate a solution for all devices.

Comment: Not to 100 to int scalingFactor = ((float)800/(float)1063)*100

Comment: The point that I am trying to make is I cannot use 1063. This value appears for only one device i.e. for a tablet. If I use a 240*320 device this value will change and the scaling factor calculated using your approach will be wrong for it. Hence I need the reason for this value occurring.